# Create and use covariant and mutable list (or potential workaround)

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I'm currently modifying a [Blazor library](https://github.com/mariusmuntean/ChartJs.Blazor) and the souce code of the current state is available [on gitlab](https://gitlab.com/bstlng321/dynamicchartjsblazor/tree/CovariantChartData).

My situation is as follows:

I have a `LineChartData` object which is supposed to store multiple Datasets for LineCharts.
These Datasets intern have a List of Data. Instead of just working with `List<object>` I wanted to be able to have `List<TData>`.
Because there is a Mixed Chart which can accept both LineChartDatasets and BarChartDatasets, there is an interface called `IMixableDataset`.

I started by making this interface generic so it now looks like this (simplified):

```
public interface IMixableDataset<TData>
{
    List<TData> Data { get; }
}
```

I then made my implementing class (`LineChartDataset`) generic as well and it now looks like this (simplified):

```
public class LineChartDataset<TData> : IMixableDataset<TData>
{
    public List<TData> Data { get; }
}
```

Next up was `LineChartData`. I first made this generic as well and continued with that until I reached the top level (see current state of my master branch). However I later wanted to change this because I wanted to support multiple Datasets with different kind of values. For this reason I reverted the generic stuff in all classes "above" the Datasets and the `LineChartData` now looks like this (simplified):

```
public class LineChartData
{
    // HashSet to avoid duplicates
    public HashSet<LineChartDataset<object>> Datasets { get; }
}
```

I decided to go with `LineChartDataset<object>` because: Since everything is castable to object, (in my mind) `XYZ<Whatever>` should also be castable to `XYZ<object>` but as I learned, this is not the case.

The where keyword didn't help either since I don't want to enforce `TData` to have relations apart from `object` - it could be `int`, `string` or something completely different. The only relation these `LineDataset`s are supposed to have is that they are `LineDataset`s, not what type they contain.

I then learned about Covariance and Contravariance (out and in-keyword). I tried out to make `TData` in `IMixableDataset` covariant but since `List` and `IList`/`ICollection` are all invariant I was unable to persue.
I also read about `IReadOnlyCollection<>` which is covariant but I cannot use this because I have to be able to modify the list after creation.

I have also tried using implicit/explicit operators to convert `LineChartDataset<whatever>` to `LineChartDataset<object>` but this has a few issues:

- Since I created a new instance, I would need to store and use the new instance instead of the original one to add items, completely destroying the typesafety I had with the original one.
- Since there are many more properties in `LineChartDataset` I would have to clone all of them as well.

If there is a way to convert a more specific one to the other **while preserving the instance and not having to write code for every property** this might be a solution.

Complete sample which reproduces the error I get and shows the issue:

```
// Provides access to some Data of a certain Type for multiple Charts
public interface IMixableDataset<TData>
{
    List<TData> Data { get; }
}

// Contains Data of a certain Type (and more) for a Line-Chart
public class LineChartDataset<TData> : IMixableDataset<TData>
{
    public List<TData> Data { get; } = new List<TData>();
}

// Contains Datasets (and more) for a Line-Chart
// This class should not be generic since I don't want to restrict what values the Datasets have. 
// I only want to ensure that each Dataset intern only has one type of data.
public class LineChartData
{
    // HashSet to avoid duplicates and Public because it has to be serialized by JSON.Net
    public HashSet<LineChartDataset<object>> Datasets { get; } = new HashSet<LineChartDataset<object>>();
}

// Contains the ChartData (with all the Datasets) and more
public class LineChartConfig
{
    public LineChartData ChartData { get; } = new LineChartData();
}

public class Demo
{
    public void DesiredUseCase()
    {
        LineChartConfig config = new LineChartConfig();

        LineChartDataset<int> intDataset = new LineChartDataset<int>();
        intDataset.Data.AddRange(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });

        config.ChartData.Datasets.Add(intDataset);
        // the above line yields following compiler error:
        // cannot convert from 'Demo.LineChartDataset<int>' to 'Demo.LineChartDataset<object>'

        // the config will then get serialized to json and used to invoke some javascript
    }

    public void WorkingButBadUseCase()
    {
        LineChartConfig config = new LineChartConfig();

        LineChartDataset<object> intDataset = new LineChartDataset<object>();
        // this allows mixed data which is exactly what I'm trying to prevent
        intDataset.Data.AddRange(new object[] { 1, 2.9, 3, 4, 5, "oops there's a string" });

        config.ChartData.Datasets.Add(intDataset); // <-- No compiler error

        // the config will then get serialized to json and used to invoke some javascript
    }
}
```

The reason everything only has getters is because of my initial attempt with using `out`. Even thought this didn't work out, I learned that you usually don't expose Setters for Collection-properties. This is not fix and also not very important for the question but I think worth mentioning.

Second complete example. Here I'm using `out` and an `IReadOnlyCollection`. I have removed the descriptions of the class (already visible in the previous example) to make it shorter.

```
public interface IMixableDataset<out TData>
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<TData> Data { get; }
}

public class LineChartDataset<TData> : IMixableDataset<TData>
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<TData> Data { get; } = new List<TData>();
}

public class LineChartData
{
    public HashSet<IMixableDataset<object>> Datasets { get; } = new HashSet<IMixableDataset<object>>();
}

public class LineChartConfig
{
    public LineChartData ChartData { get; } = new LineChartData();
}

public class Demo
{
    public void DesiredUseCase()
    {
        LineChartConfig config = new LineChartConfig();

        IMixableDataset<int> intDataset = new LineChartDataset<int>();
        // since it's ReadOnly, I of course can't add anything so this yields a compiler error.
        // For my use case, I do need to be able to add items to the list.
        intDataset.Data.AddRange(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }); 

        config.ChartData.Datasets.Add(intDataset);
        // the above line yields following compiler error (which fairly surprised me because I thought I correctly used out):
        // cannot convert from 'Demo.IMixableDataset<int>' to 'Demo.IMixableDataset<object>'
    }
}
```

So the question:
**Is there anyway to have a mutable and covariant collection?

If not, is there a workaround or something I can do to achieve this functionality?**

Additional stuff:

- I'm using the newest version of everything (.net core, VS, blazor, C#). Since the library is .NET Standard I'm still on C# 7.3 there.
- In the repo under [WebCore/Pages/FetchData](https://gitlab.com/bstlng321/dynamicchartjsblazor/blob/CovariantChartData/WebCore/Pages/FetchData.razor) you can perfectly see what I want to achieve (see comments at the end of the file).

Comment: How do you plan to use that HashSet?  Will you every pull a chart out and attempt to get or add strongly typed values?  If not, I'd suggest an interface that exposes only what you need from the charts in the HashSet.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean. Using the hashset directly isn't the best choice because just adding and removing would be enough. The developer is supposed to store a reference to the Dataset they pass in if they want to modify the data later. The hashset is only public because json.net wont serialize it otherwise :/ have not found a way around that yet.

Comment: Then have you just tried a `HashSet<object>`?  Is this completely a serialization/deserialization problem?  If so you might have to do some custom code to handle the serialization and deserialization.

Comment: _"Is there anyway to have a mutable and covariant collection?"_ -- no. Doing so would violate the basic premise of covariance. Mutability implies being able to both copy values into, and copy values out of, the collection. Any time you can do that, if you were to allow a base type collection to represent a more-derived type collection, you run the risk of allowing an element of the wrong type to be added to the collection. It is unclear from your post what "this functionality" actually is; if you really want covariant use of the collection, then no...

Comment: ...that's the whole point of prohibiting it. But it might be that you could just use the `IMixableDataset` interface directly as the type parameter, or maybe you should be using `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` in the interface, but then providing mutation via casting back to a type that provides the mutating part of the API (in the same way that `List<T>` implements the covariant `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, even though `List<T>` itself is not covariant).

Comment: You should post a good [mcve] that has a complete-but-minimally-simple example of what you are actually trying to do, compiler errors and all. It's hard to understand from your narrative what the exact goal is here, but code is universal and (usually) unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive critisism. I will try to edit my question in a manner that shows the issue more clearly. Also I might have misunderstood the concept of covariance because you said "if you were to allow a base type collection to represent a more-derived type collection, you run the risk of allowing an element of the wrong type to be added to the collection" but I thought that's exactly the opposite of what I'm trying to do. I'm not trying to represent `List<object>` as `List<string>` but rather the other way around. Did I mix up something?

Comment: @juharr I could do that but I really don't want to do that. This would allow anyone to just add anything they'd like and I really only want Datasets in that HashSet.

Comment: I would try exposing the list through two different properties, one with an interface that allows for covariance, and one with an interface that allows for contravariance.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have now added two complete examples which hopefully show my issue. I'd be happy if you'd look over it when you have time :)

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis how would you use that with a collection? I don't seem to find any contravariant collections. I have tried with a covariant "getter" interface and an invariant "setter" interface but this doesn't help me either since now I can set the value of Data but first of all I don't want to be able to do that and second I need to be able to modify the data (not necessarly change it to a new list-instance) which is still not possible since the collection is readonly.

Comment: @Joelius You could create a custom collection that exposes both a covariant and a contravariant interface. The covariant interface would be used only for reading, and the contravariant interface would be used only for writing. If your operations do not lend themselves to a design like that, then perhaps you should rethink what you're doing because C#'s type system is sound in this regard -- if it doesn't let you do it, it's just not type safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking more closely at your example, I see one major problem: you are attempting to involve value types (e.g. `int`) in type variance. For better or worse, C# type variance applies *only* to reference types.

So, no…sorry, but it is quite impossible to do exactly what you're asking. You would have to represent all value-type based collections as `object`, not as their specific value types.

Now, as far as reference-type collections go, your example will work fine, with one minor change. Here's a modified version of your second example showing it working, with that one minor change:

```
public interface IMixableDataset<out TData>
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<TData> Data { get; }
}

public class LineChartDataset<TData> : IMixableDataset<TData>
{
    private readonly List<TData> _list = new List<TData>();

    public IReadOnlyCollection<TData> Data => _list;

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TData> collection) => _list.AddRange(collection);
}

public class LineChartData
{
    public HashSet<IMixableDataset<object>> Datasets { get; } = new HashSet<IMixableDataset<object>>();
}

public class LineChartConfig
{
    public LineChartData ChartData { get; } = new LineChartData();
}

public class Demo
{
    public void DesiredUseCase()
    {
        LineChartConfig config = new LineChartConfig();

        // Must use reference types to take advantage of type variance in C#
        LineChartDataset<string> intDataset = new LineChartDataset<string>();

        // Using the non-interface method to add the range, you can still mutate the object
        intDataset.AddRange(new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" });

        // Your original code works fine when reference types are used
        config.ChartData.Datasets.Add(intDataset);
    }
}
```

In particular, note that I've added an `AddRange()` method to your `LineChartDataset<TData>` class. This provides a type-safe way to mutate the collection. Note that the code that wants to mutate the collection must know the correct type, bypassing the variance restrictions.

The variant interface `IMixableDataset<TData>` itself cannot, of course, include a way to add things, because this would not be type-safe. You would be able to treat your `LineChartDataset<string>` as a `IMixableDataset<object>`, and then if you could add things via that interface, you'd be able to add some other type of object, even a non-reference type like a boxed `int` value, to your collection that's supposed to only contain `string` objects.

But, just as the invariant `List<T>` can implement the covariant `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, your concrete `LineChartDataset<TData>` class can implement `IMixableDataset<TData>` while still providing a mechanism for adding items. This works because while the concrete type determines what the object can actually do, the interfaces simply define a contract that users of the reference must abide by, allowing the compiler to ensure type safety where the interface is used, even when used in a variant way. (The invariant concrete type ensures type safety as well, but only because the type has to match *exactly*, which is of course more restrictive/less flexible.)

If you don't mind using `object` in place of any specific value type for the value-type-based collections, then the above would work. It's a bit clumsy, since any time you actually want to get the value type values out, you'd need to retrieve them as `object` and then cast as necessary to actually use them. But at least the broader variant approach would then succeed, and no special handling would be required for any reference types.

Aside: that type variance in C# is restricted to reference types is based on the pragmatic requirement that type variance doesn't affect the runtime code. It's just a compile-time type-conversion. This means that you have to be able to just copy references around. To support value types would require adding new boxing and unboxing logic where it otherwise wouldn't exist. It's also not quite as useful, because value types don't have the same rich degree of type inheritance that reference types can have (value types can only ever inherit `object`, so variant scenarios are much less useful and interesting, in general).

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer. Sadly it looks like what I would want isn't possible. For my use case I don't really need to be able to retrieve the values again so it probably wouldn't be an issue to just box all the value types right (json.net understands boxed value-types)? Is there any way to do that without allowing the user to add different kinds of values?

Comment: The workaround I'm currently thinking of would be to take your solution and add a type constraint `where TData : class` so I cannot use value types there. Then I would manually add an `IntDataset`, a `DoubleDataset` and maybe a `DecimalDataset`. Is this an acceptable workaround or is there something particular you would suggest?

Comment: I just tried this (my last comment) and it doesn't work as well (should have known that - why would it be convertable if you extract it into a new class). I have currently no other idea than creating a new Dataset containing objects and adding all the values to it after boxing them as object. This seems like a bad solution and I lose important functionality. Using a wrapper to make value types work with reference types also seems pretty bad. Is there any other way to make this collection work? I can go fairly far in terms of changing the whole concept if it's needed.

Comment: Your thought to restrict to reference types seems reasonable to me. However, instead of creating type-specific `Dataset` implementations, consider creating type-specific value wrappers. E.g. `class ReferenceInt32 { public int Value { get; } public ReferenceInt32(int value) { Value = value; } }`, etc. Then e.g. `LineChartDataset<ReferenceInt32>`, etc. This is just like boxing, but in a type-safe way. You'll have to add serialization-friendly features to each wrapper for JSON.

Comment: Okay so you think this is the next best way? This was the only thing left over in my imagination. I'll implement it like this. Thank you very much!